`ddev import-db` or `ddev pull` - Error: Unknown command '\-'
I'm trying to import a zipped sql dump into ddev like this: ddev import-db --file=database.sql.gz but that gives me the following error:
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\-'.
If I try ddev import-db < database.sql.gz I get this error:
ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: ''.


(This also happens on ddev pull platform, for example, because it uses the same technique, downloading a sql dump created by new version of mariadb-backup/mysqldump.)

This is a result of a recent change in MariaDB dump file format. You can see the full information at https://mariadb.org/mariadb-dump-file-compatibility-change/
Edit 2024-05-27: ddev import-db is fixed for DDEV v1.23.1 by pushing new ddev-dbserver.  You may need to pull new docker images; use the instructions in https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/6249
You'll need to take one of the actions mentioned in that article to sort it out.
Related DDEV issues are

https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/6249
https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/6083#issuecomment-2116597297

This was a very unfortunate change for MariaDB to make in a patch version of their product. People are feeling the pain all over the internet.
